# How find the $\Delta_{n}(k_{1},x_{1};k_{2},x_{2};\cdots;k_{m},x_{m})=\prod_{1\le j<i\le m}(x_{i}-x_{j})^{k_{i}k_{j}}$

Tags: matrices

let
$$\Delta_{n}(k_{1},x_{1};k_{2},x_{2};\cdots;k_{m},x_{m})=
\begin{vmatrix}
M^n_{k_{1}}(x_{1})\\
M^n_{k_{2}}(x_{2})\\
\cdots\cdots\\
M^n_{k_{m}}(x_{m})
\end{vmatrix}$$
where $k_{1},k_{2},\cdots,k_{m}\in N,k_{1}+k_{2}+\cdots+k_{m}=n$,and 
$$M^n_{k}(x)=\begin{bmatrix}
1&x&x^2&\cdots x^{n-1}\\
0&1&\binom{2}{1}x&\cdots&\binom{n-1}{1}x^{n-2}\\
0&0&1&\cdots&\binom{n-1}{2}x^{n-3}\\
\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots\\
0&0&0&\cdots&\binom{n-1}{k-1}x^{n-k}
\end{bmatrix}$$
show that
$$\Delta_{n}(k_{1},x_{1};k_{2},x_{2};\cdots;k_{m},x_{m})=\prod_{1\le j<i\le m}(x_{i}-x_{j})^{k_{i}k_{j}}$$

my book Hint:when $k_{1}=k_{2}=\cdots=k_{m}=1$,mean $m=n$,it can Get the vandermonde determinant

How prove it ,I guess This problem not hard,and I guess this problem have nice methods,Thank you everyone.

[image]

Comment: What book is that? It is **never** more helpful to say «my book» than to give a precise reference!

Comment: Also: how can you tell the problem is not very hard? :-)

Comment: @math110 You have always  nice questions.

Comment: HaHa @SamiBenRomdhane,Thank you,This problem is nice

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez,I have edit, is from china book (矩阵论),This

Comment: This book: http://www.amazon.cn/%E7%8E%B0%E4%BB%A3%E6%95%B0%E5%AD%A6%E5%9F%BA%E7%A1%80-%E7%BA%BF%E6%80%A7%E4%BB%A3%E6%95%B0%E4%B8%8E%E7%9F%A9%E9%98%B5%E8%AE%BA-%E8%AE%B8%E4%BB%A5%E8%B6%85/dp/B001DHI61E/ref=sr_1_6?ie=UTF8&qid=1373168714&sr=8-6&keywords=%E7%9F%A9%E9%98%B5%E8%AE%BA

Comment: I don't understand how you're supposed to build a square matrix with k x k matrices of different sizes

Comment: 线性代数 ( xiànxìng dàishù ) = "linear algebra"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this link:
http://www.garretstar.com/secciones/publications/docs/generalized_Vandermonde.pdf

Very nice inductive proof. The main idea is to take partial derivative with respect to a variable $x_j$ while holding the rest fixed. Note that the $i$-th row of your block matrix is the $i$-th order derivative (divided by some constant) of the first row.